# How to get any text between an opening and closing node with xpath?

Tags: xpath

I want to get the specified text as in example but when I used `strong[3]` but it returns "Text5:" as expected. How can I get the airport name section with xpath?

Code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <strong>Text1 </strong>Text2
    <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Text3: </strong>Text4 &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <strong>Text5:</strong> Text_Text_Text_Text_Text
  </td>
</tr>
```

The part that I need:

```
Text_Text_Text_Text_Text
```

Comment: Looks like the third text node to me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is /tr/td/text()[3]